# Edit everything as a privilege?

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges

I was looking the new [privileges page over on gaming.stackexchange.com](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges) today, when I noticed this:
[image]

You can "edit everything" before you can edit tag wikis. It appears that over on [Stack Exchange's](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges), editing the tag wikis does come first, so I can see how this happened, but I think that it should be changed to "Edit all questions and answers", especially since that's what it says on [that page anyway](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit). Besides, you can't literally edit everything.

Comment: belongs on meta.gaming... also [related](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1221/reputation-requirements-have-not-been-changed)

Comment: well, it applies to all beta sites, that's just the one I'm most active on.

Comment: It applies to all sites, even on SO it is written "Edit everything".

Comment: Yeah, but it's only in reverse order on the beta sites AFAIK.

Comment: fixed in dev, will be deployed today

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yeah, I think I got a little overzealous with the naming here

> edit questions and answers

is certainly better and more accurate than

> edit everything