# How much reputation do you need to edit the privileges wiki?

Tags: support, edits, privileges, privileges-page

Related:

- [Edit everything as a privilege?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66941/edit-everything-as-a-privilege)

It *looks* as if you *probably* gain the ability to edit privilege wikis at the same level you gain "edit questions and answers" ability, however the privilege wiki entry for that privilege level fails to mention that you can then edit the **privilege wiki** as well.

Can someone confirm/deny that editing the privilege wiki requires the same privilege level as what used to be labeled "edit everything" but has since been revised to "edit questions and answers"?

Comment: I used _your_ words in the title. The previous title had me off on some other tangent. Perhaps _you_ can suggest _a better_ title than either of the two proposed titles?

Answer (score 12):

Only Stack Exchange employees can edit Privileges pages after [they moved to the Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center).

Moderators, 10k and 20k are no longer on that access list.

If you see something that needs a fix, open up a new request and tag it [help-center](/questions/tagged/help-center).

Comment: We should get an other obsolete close reason for meta - not only for bug reports.

Comment: Obsolete can also apply to things whisked out of existence, like bug reports, so you still use the same close reason.